# Reduce long list of parameters

Tags: c#

Is there a way to reduce long lists of parameters in C#. Currently I have:

```
public ActionResult GetSubmitFields(string orcid, string firstName, string lastName, string badgeName)
{
    UserCreateModel vUserTemp = new UserCreateModel();
    vUserTemp.OrcidID = orcid;
    vUserTemp.FirstName = firstName;
    vUserTemp.LastName = lastName;
    vUserTemp.BadgeName = badgeName;
    return Json(vUserTemp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

But in reality, I have about 20 parameters I will pass and I don't want to write a long vertical list adding each variable.

Comment: Pass a custom object/class instead that incorporates all of your variables.  Honestly, this is all a matter of opinion and depends on the requirements.

Comment: I'm just trying to write efficient code and C# is not my strong suit, so that's why I'm asking

Comment: I would suggest passing an Interface as your parameter.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with an interface, how does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is commonly used is a data container for transporting such objects. These are classes or structs that just hold data but do nothing else.

An example could be Microsofts `XmlReaderSettings` class that feeds the XmlReader with information: [XmlReaderSettings Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you have a method like the one you posted and you want to fill the properties of a new object (like you do) you can also write this:

```
public ActionResult GetSubmitFields(string orcid, string firstName, string lastName, string badgeName)
{
    UserCreateModel vUserTemp = new UserCreateModel() { OrcidID = orcid, FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastName, BadgeName = badgeName };
    return Json(vUserTemp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This initializes the `public` properties with the given values. The other properties are getting their default values assigned like they would normally get.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can simplify the syntax somewhat, but the list is going to remain in place:

```
public ActionResult GetSubmitFields(string orcid, string firstName, string lastName, string badgeName) {
    return Json(
        new UserCreateModel {
            OrcidID = orcid
        ,   FirstName = firstName
        ,   LastName = lastName
        ,   BadgeName = badgeName
        }
    ,   JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    );
}
```

Second, you can use `dynamic` to remove parameter list:

```
public ActionResult GetSubmitFields(dynamic user) {
    return Json(
        new UserCreateModel {
            OrcidID = user.OrcId
        ,   FirstName = user.FirstName
        ,   LastName = user.lastName
        ,   BadgeName = user.badgeName
        }
    ,   JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    );
}
```

The call of the method should look like this:

```
var json = GetSubmitFields( new {
    OrcId = 1234
,   FirstName = "Keith"
,   LastName = "Smith"
,   BadgeName = "Ninja"
});
```

The list of field names is still there, but now the compiler has no way to verify their types. If, say, `OrcId` happens to be set to a `string`, while `UserCreateModel` expects an `int`, the error would not be detected until the run time.